# Elixir: array to function arguments

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir. I use the [redix](https://github.com/whatyouhide/redix/) library to work with Redis. I can't manage to execute MGET command properly.
This code works:

```
Like4uElixir.RedixPool.command(["MGET", "a", "b", "c"])
```

- it returns 3 values from Redis.
But this code doesn't work:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
Like4uElixir.RedixPool.command(["MGET", keys])
```

But I have all the keys in array. How can I convert my array to a number of function arguments?

Comment: If @Gazler answered your question, you should  accept his answer as the right one.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci done it. Didn't see the button first :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're code samples aren't the same. You are creating a nested list instead of creating a single list with 4 elements.

You're second example does:

```
["MGET", ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

You want to do:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
Like4uElixir.RedixPool.command(["MGET" | keys])
#or Like4uElixir.RedixPool.command(["MGET"] ++ keys)
```

Comment: OMG, so easy! :) it was my typo, thank you. I thougth(don't know why) it was function arguments, not a list.

Comment: Slightly more idiomatic maybe `["MGET" | keys]`. Also s/you're/your/ ;-)

Comment: @cdegroot Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The use of the cons operator is more idiomatic. However, if you already had a list of arguments, you could use `Kernel.apply`. Just an FYI.